# Looking for command to get only "Root Path"

Tags: cmd

When I am executing command `logman FabricTraces` in a command prompt window, I get output many attributes and their values as shown below:

```
Name:                 FabricTraces
Status:               Running
Root Path:            C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces\
Segment:              On
Schedules:            On
Segment Max Size:     128 MB
Run as:               SYSTEM
```

Is there any command to get only `Root Path` value?

Comment: Thanks Mofi for editing the code

Comment: If you need a C# solution (as stated in the comments to answers), you should tag your question correctly. Since there are valid cmd solutions already, I’d recommend asking another question. (You can link this question from the new one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a similar effect of the `grep` utility in windows by using `findstr`:

`logman FabricTraces | findstr "Root Path:"`

-

Source: https://www.mkyong.com/linux/grep-for-windows-findstr-example/

Comment: Note: `findstr "Root Path:"` will return every line that contains `Root` and/or `Path:` (not a problem with this special output, but may give unexpected results with other commands). To find the exact string (including a space`, use `findstr /c:"Root Path:"`. You may also want the `/b` switch. See `findstr /?` for more details

Comment: @Stephan, Is there any way to get only "Value"?

Comment: @user584018: see my answer.

Comment: result are in multiple lines. Is there a way to get result in after hitting command

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('logman FabricTraces^|find "Root Path"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%r in ("%%b") do set rootpath=%%r
echo %rootpath%
```

first `for` is to get the desired string, second `for` is to remove leading spaces.

According to your comment, you need a one-liner to use it in `C#`:

```
cmd /c "@for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %a in ('logman FabricTraces^|find "Root Path"') do @for /f "tokens=*" %r in ("%b") do @echo %r "
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan, if we need to run in C# and get output into a variable, how to do this?

Comment: please suggest and help

Comment: Included a one-liner to output the value. How to get it in a C# variable is your concern - I don't know C#.

Answer (score 1):

Is piping the output and option? If so you could use `findstr` in windows or `grep` if it is a Linux base system.

Windows:

```
logman FabricTraces | findstr Root
```

Linux:

```
logman FabricTraces | grep Root
```

This should show only the Root Path line in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\logman.exe FabricTraces 2^>nul') do if "%%A %%B" == "Root Path:" set "RootPath=%%C" & goto RootPath
echo Failed to get root path for FabricTraces.
goto :EOF

:RootPath
echo Root path for FabricTraces is: %RootPath%
rem More commands using environment variable RootPath.
```

A little bit optimized with using `:` as delimiter instead of the defaults tab and space:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\logman.exe FabricTraces 2^>nul') do if "%%A" == "Root Path" set "RootPath=%%B" & goto RootPath
echo Failed to get root path for FabricTraces.
goto :EOF

:RootPath
echo Root path for FabricTraces is: %RootPath%
rem More commands using environment variable RootPath.
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `logman /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `logman.exe` command line with using a separate command process started in background.